# Using a SQL parameter when querying iHistorian

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL to query iHistorian through a linked server.  I want to loop through different tagnames from a SQL table.  The problem I have is adding the parameter to the ihistorian query.  The code is as follows.  I haven't included the declare on tagname as its not relevant at this point.

```
    SELECT timestamp AS Interval, Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) as TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), ROUND(value, 3)) As Value, quality 
FROM 
   OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,'
                SET starttime =''yesterday '', endtime =''yesterday +1h''  
                SELECT timestamp, tagname, value, ihRawData.quality 
                FROM ihRawData
                WHERE tagname = '+ @tagname +' 
                AND timestamp BETWEEN ''timestamp'' and ''timestamp'' 
                AND SamplingMode =Calculated
                AND CalculationMode =Average
                AND IntervalMilliseconds =1h
                ORDER BY tagname, timestamp')
                end
```

The problem I am having is at the `WHERE tagname = '+ @tagname +'`  point.  The query doesn't like the  `'+ @tagname +'`.  It underlines the first `+` and says a `)` is expected.

I basically want to set the tagname independently of the historian query as stated earlier.

Full Query --

```
use Optimiser_Test;

declare @tagname varchar(32)
--declare @rowcount int
--declare @maxrows int
--select @maxrows = count(*) from OptimiserTags

--set @rowcount = 0

set @tagname = 'UMIS.99FE1100.F_CV'

--while @rowcount < @maxrows
begin


SELECT timestamp AS Interval, Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) as TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), ROUND(value, 3)) As Value, quality 
FROM 
   OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,'
                SET starttime =''yesterday '', endtime =''yesterday +1h''  
                SELECT timestamp, tagname, value, ihRawData.quality 
                FROM ihRawData
                WHERE tagname = REPLACE(@tagName, '''','')
                AND timestamp BETWEEN ''timestamp'' and ''timestamp'' 
                AND SamplingMode =Calculated
                AND CalculationMode =Average
                AND IntervalMilliseconds =1h
                ORDER BY tagname, timestamp')
                end
```

NEW UPDATE --

```
use Optimiser_Test;


declare @tagname varchar(32)
declare @fullquery varchar(1000)

set @fullquery = 'SELECT timestamp AS Interval, Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) as TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), ROUND(value, 3)) As Value, quality 
FROM 
   OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,
                SET starttime =''yesterday '', endtime =''yesterday +1h''  
                SELECT timestamp, tagname, value, ihRawData.quality 
                FROM ihRawData
                WHERE tagname = '''+ @tagname +'''
                AND timestamp BETWEEN ''timestamp'' and ''timestamp'' 
                AND SamplingMode =Calculated
                AND CalculationMode =Average
                AND IntervalMilliseconds =1h
                ORDER BY tagname, timestamp'''''

begin
set @tagname = 'UMIS.99FE1100.F_CV'
exec (@fullquery)

end
```

New Update 2 --

If I run the query with the tagname specified in the query as below I get the following result.  Which is correct.

```
use Optimiser_Test;

SELECT timestamp AS Interval, Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) as TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), ROUND(value, 3)) As Value, quality 
FROM 
   OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,'
                SET starttime =''yesterday '', endtime =''yesterday +1h''  
                SELECT timestamp, tagname, value, ihRawData.quality 
                FROM ihRawData
                WHERE tagname = UMIS.99FE1100.F_CV
                AND timestamp BETWEEN ''timestamp'' and ''timestamp'' 
                AND SamplingMode =Calculated
                AND CalculationMode =Average
                AND IntervalMilliseconds =1h
                ORDER BY tagname, timestamp')
```

Result

[image]

After numerous back and forths with James S below and some further work with my colleagues I got to this which returns what I need.

```
Declare @SQLString varchar(1000)
Declare @TAGS VarChar(1000)

Set @Tags = '"UMIS.99FE1100.F_CV"'

SET @SQLString = 'SELECT timestamp AS Interval, Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) as TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), ROUND(value, 3)) As Value, quality 
FROM 
   OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,''
                SET starttime =''''yesterday '''', endtime =''''yesterday +1h'''',
                         SELECT timestamp, tagname, value, ihRawData.quality 
                FROM ihRawData
                WHERE tagname = ' + @Tags + '
                           and IntervalMilliseconds =1h,  
                           and CalculationMode =Average,
                           and SamplingMode =Calculated
                ORDER BY tagname, timestamp'')
                           '

Print @SQLString
Print @Tags
Exec (@SQLString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is missing the quotes around @tagname (assuming it is a string)
However I think there are other syntax issues besides just that one!

but is there a reason for using OPENQUERY, rather than just executing the SQL directly refering to the source table by it's four part name: server.database.schema.table ?

anyway you should convert the line: `WHERE tagname = '+ @tagname +'`
to: `WHERE tagname = '''+ @tagname +'''` to get your existing query fixed.

This is of course assuming that @tagName is NOT user-input, as otherwise you are wide open to SQL injection attacks. You can use `REPLACE(@tagName, '''','')` in place of `@tagName` to get round this, but a direct query is much safer...

direct query example:

```
SET starttime ='yesterday', endtime ='yesterday +1h'

SELECT timestamp AS Interval, 
       Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) as TagName,
       CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), ROUND(value, 3)) As Value, 
       quality 
FROM IHISTORIAN.<dbname>.dbo.ihRawData
    WHERE tagname = @tagname 
        AND timestamp BETWEEN 'timestamp' and 'timestamp' 
        AND SamplingMode ='Calculated'
        AND CalculationMode ='Average'
        AND IntervalMilliseconds ='1h'
    ORDER BY tagname, timestamp
```

**EDIT**

Corrected OPENQUERY example: (but not sure what purpose the line `SET starttime =''yesterday '', endtime =''yesterday +1h''` has, so this has been removed!) NB - I've assumed SamplingMode, CalculationMode and IntervalMilliseconds should be strings, and enclosed them in escaped quoted too. The entire SQL string is now constructed first into a variable, before passing that to OPENQUERY

```
use Optimiser_Test;

declare @tagname varchar(32)
DECLARE @startTimeStamp NVARCHAR(50), @endTimeStamp NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(8000)
--declare @rowcount int
--declare @maxrows int
--select @maxrows = count(*) from OptimiserTags

--set @rowcount = 0

set @tagname = 'UMIS.99FE1100.F_CV'

--while @rowcount < @maxrows
begin

SET @startTimeStamp = 'yesterday'
SET @endTimeStamp = 'yesterday +1h'
SET @sql =     'SELECT timestamp, tagname, value, ihRawData.quality 
                FROM ihRawData
                WHERE tagname = ''' + REPLACE(@tagName, '''','') + '''
                AND timestamp BETWEEN ''' + @startTimeStamp + ''' 
                              AND ''' + @endTimeStamp + '''  
                AND SamplingMode =''Calculated''
                AND CalculationMode =''Average''
                AND IntervalMilliseconds =''1h''
                ORDER BY tagname, timestamp'

SELECT timestamp AS Interval, Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) as TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), ROUND(value, 3)) As Value, quality 
FROM 
   OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN, @sql)
                end
```

**EDIT 2**

OK - If your final query gets what you want then then all you need to do is declare a NVARCHAR variable - populate it with the SQL, and then pass that variable to openQuery. I don't think  you can build strings dynamically inside the () of a function call.

IE:

```
use Optimiser_Test;

declare @tagname varchar(32)
set @tagname = 'UMIS.99FE1100.F_CV'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL = 'SET starttime =''yesterday '', endtime =''yesterday +1h''  
                SELECT timestamp, tagname, value, ihRawData.quality 
                FROM ihRawData
                WHERE tagname = ' + @tagname + '
                AND timestamp BETWEEN ''timestamp'' and ''timestamp'' 
                AND SamplingMode =Calculated
                AND CalculationMode =Average
                AND IntervalMilliseconds =1h
                ORDER BY tagname, timestamp'
SELECT timestamp AS Interval, Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) as TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), ROUND(value, 3)) As Value, quality 
FROM 
   OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,@SQL)
```

Comment: James S - thanks for the advice.  Due to our setup I cant directly reference the historian DB.  adding in the 3 ' doesn't work, same error.  I am setting @tagname myself and its a string.

Comment: Ive added the full query above,  using the REPLACE suggestion.  Im still doing something wrong as I get nothing back even though if I put the full tag name into the query I get a result.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly, and removed the line `SET starttime...` because it didn't seem to serve a purpose, and is likely to cause an error on the remote server. Also the line `AND timestamp BETWEEN ...` will need editing - as presumably those should be variables!

Comment: still not having it, same error on the + and also incorrect syntax error on @tagname.  The start and end define the time range in historian i.e. I want the average between these times.  This works when I directly add the tagname into the query.

Comment: ok, try the above - I've changed it so the SQL is contructed into a variable first, and then that variable is passed to OPENQUERY, which should make things more readable. I've also made new variables `@startTimeStamp` and `@endTimeStamp`, as I would assume you want to vary these - and again the values are build into the SQL string. If its still not working then post a few sample expected result rows

Comment: I have edited mine and I get Commands executed successfully but I cant see the results.  arrrggghhhh!!!

Comment: ok I assume some of the where criteria is wrong - what datatypes are all your columns? Am I correct in assuming SamplingMode is a (N)VARCHAR column for example? What sort of values are in the timestamp column (because I'd be surprised if they were literally strings that said 'yesterday') etc

Comment: righto try the last edited version and see if that works for you